# Inject a shopify page through shopify-api in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-api

Im trying to inject a new page to a shopify-store through the shopify-api which is included in the shopify-app gem. I added the authentication from the gem to my controller, which works perfect for GET-requests. Somehow the POST-Method does not work.

The method inject_page_method shall be called in my create method, which would then represent a second POST request.

Im confused, because the GET-methods already work. So I thought, the gem routes this endpoints for me like this:

```
def inject_page_method
  @create_new_page = ShopifyAPI::Page.new(:title => "test", :body_html =>"<h1>Test</h1>")
  @create_new_page.save
end
helper_method :inject_page_method
```

Finding out this does not work I tried it with a full endpoint request:

```
def create_new_page

  page_data = {
    "page": {
      "title": "Test",
      "body_html": "<h1>Test succeded</h1>"
    }
  }

  @json_request_url = @shop_domain + "/admin/api/2020-07/pages.json"

  Rails.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:@json_request_url,
    data:page_data
  })
end
```

Heroku logs --tail shows me, that the method is POST, which is fine, but I get a status=500 with following errors:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/my_controller.rb:101:in `create_new_page'
app/controllers/my_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

When I change the concatenation of @json_request_url to:

```
@json_request_url = "#{@shop_domain}/admin/api/2020-07/pages.json"
```

I get a status 500:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ajax' for Rails:Module):
```

Which is impossible because both Jquery and Rails/ujs are required in the application.js

Edit: This is on rails 6

What is missing?

Comment: Can you add more information about the errors you're getting?

Comment: line 37 is calling my "create_new_page" method by my create-method. Line 101 is the line with the concatenation

Comment: The `@shop_domain` variable is nil. Try checking where it's defined.

Comment: Its defined in the same controller as private method and called in the before_action without any restrictions. As it becomes not nil, suddenly "ajax" is an undefined method